# why does the android bundling keep failing?

Tags: react-native

I'm running a react-native app, but my metro bundler keeps failing.

I have tried updating and installing the expected versions of the dependencies, but i keep getting the below error;

*Unable to resolve "@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault" from "node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js"*

Comment: Did you install  NPM dependencies with Expo - `expo install`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've resolved the issue, it was a rookie mistake.